# OpenGL Camera Movement - Shader vs. Primitive Rendering

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In my OpenGL application, I am using `gluLookAt()` for transforming my camera. I then have two different render functions; one uses primitive rendering (`glBegin()/glEnd()`) to render a triangle.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.25, -0.25, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.5);
glEnd();
```

The second rendering function uses a shader to display the triangle using the same coordinates and is called with the function `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)`. shader.vert is shown below:

```
#version 430 core

void main()
{
   const vec4 verts[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1),
                         vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1),
                         vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1));
   gl_Position = verts[gl_VertexID];
}
```

Now here is my problem; if I move the camera around using the primitive rendering for the triangle, I see the triangle from different angles like one would expect. When I use the shader rendering function, the triangle remains stationary. Clearly I am missing something about world coordinates and how they related to objects rendered with shaders. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have an active shader program, you're using what is called the "fixed pipeline". The fixed pipeline performs rendering based on numerous attributes you set with OpenGL API calls. For example, you specify what transformations you want to apply. You specify material and light attributes that control the lighting of your geometry. Applying these attributes is then handled by OpenGL.

Once you use your own shader program, you're not using the fixed pipeline anymore. This means that most of what the fixed pipeline previously handled for you has to be implemented in your shader code. Applying transformations is part of this. To apply your transformation matrix, you have to pass it into the shader, and apply it in your shader code.

The matrix is typically declared as a `uniform` variable in your vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 ModelViewProj;
```

and then applied to your vertices:

```
gl_Position = ModelViewProj * verts[gl_VertexID];
```

In your code, you will then use calls like `glGetUniformLocation()`, `glUniformMatrix4fv()`, etc., to set up the matrix. Explaining this in full detail is somewhat beyond this answer, but you should be able to find it in many OpenGL tutorials online.

As long as you're still using legacy functionality with the Compatibility Profile, there's actually a simpler way. You should be aware that this is deprecated, and not available in the OpenGL Core Profile. The Compatibility Profile makes certain fixed function attributes available to your shader code, including the transformation matrices. So you do not have to declare anything, and can simply write:

```
gl_Position =  gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * verts[gl_VertexID];
```